# 1980's Young Adult UFO abduction novel

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Hardback by an American writer, possibly a female. Has an SF plot but was marketed as a 'young adult with problem' story. YA audience, may have a one-word title. Teenage boy disappears after a UFO sighting (possibly near a lake). After some missing time (days, I think) he is returned to Earth, unharmed & with no memory of what happened. The boy never remembers what happened aboard the UFO; the entire story describes the aftermath of his experience, how he deals with the problems fame brings him.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 2):

Your brief synopsis seems a lot like the 1986 movie *Flight of the Navigator* in which a 12-yer-old boy disappears and returns 8 years later but not a day older.  But I have been unable to find out if there was a novelization of *Flight of the Navigator* published.

Comment: It does resemble Flight of the Navigator (makes me wonder which came first), but that is not the story I am looking for. As far as I can remember this book had nothing to do with Hollywood.